# Unknown type name 'SKPaymentDiscount'. FBSDKCoreKit

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift3, facebook-ios-sdk

I am facing an issue when building the Facebook sdk for iOS `facebook-ios-sdk` in my **Swift 3 iOS application**.

I have recently updated the `FBSDKCorekit` and `FBSDKLoginkit` pods I'm using in my iOS application from version **4.30.0** to **5.13.1**

I am using XCode 9.3.1 targeting iOS 10.2. when building my application with XCode I get the following issue: **Unknown type name 'SKPaymentDiscount'; did you mean 'SKProductDiscount'?**

This error is raised when the compiler attempts to build the following file `Core/FBSDKPaymentObserver.m`. See the following segment.

```
...
#if !TARGET_OS_TV
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > __IPHONE_11_1
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > __IPHONE_11_4
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > __IPHONE_12_1
  // promotional offer starting from iOS 12.2
  if (@available(iOS 12.2, *)) {
    SKPaymentDiscount *paymentDiscount = transaction.payment.paymentDiscount;
    if (paymentDiscount) {
      NSArray<SKProductDiscount *> *discounts = product.discounts;
      for (SKProductDiscount *discount in discounts) {
        if (discount.paymentMode == SKProductDiscountPaymentModeFreeTrial &&
            [paymentDiscount.identifier isEqualToString:discount.identifier]) {
          return YES;
        }
      }
    }
  }
#endif
...
```

As I understood after doing some research, `SKPaymentDiscount` was only introduced in iOS sdk 12.2 . Since I am using XCode 9.3.1 the latest available iOS SDK is 11.3 but the conditional compiler expression `#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > __IPHONE_12_1`
should make sure the compiler does not build the previous code segment.

However that doesn't seem to be the case and I am getting the build error.
**Unknown type name 'SKPaymentDiscount'; did you mean 'SKProductDiscount'?**

I have tried installing XCode 10.0 which supports iOS sdk 12.2 but I got the same error. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You should update to Xcode 11.3.1. It is the latest version currently as of Jan 2020.